# convert binary variable into unique group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a binary variable (Var C) that identifies when another variable (Var B) is above or below a different variable (Var A).  There is typically a series of the same value for Var C.  I'd like to make a new variable (Var D) that represents the unique group of data for the time in between switches.

Hope this helps

```
 VarA VarB VarC VarD
  30   28   1    1
  32   28   1    1
  33   30   1    1
  32   32   1    1
  34   33   1    1
  35   36   0    2
  37   38   0    2
  38   39   0    2
  39   39   0    2
  40   39   1    3
  38   37   1    3
  37   36   1    3
  35   33   1    3
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in columns `A` through `C` you can assign value `1` to cell `D2` and use the following formula for the rest of the rows:

```
=IF(C3<>C2,D2+1,D2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **D2** enter **1**

In **D3** enter:

```
=IF(C3=C2,D2,D2+1)
```

and copy downward.

[image]